# Assign alternating values on dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have some data that I need to divide into 4 equal bins based on a certain measure (Hourly Rate). In certain cases, some rows in my dataframe have the same Hourly Rate. Most of the time, that doesn't cause a problem. But there are cases when some of the data that share the same Hourly Rate go in one bin and the rest go in another one. My requirement is for these two counts (the one that goes into the first bin and the one that goes into the second) to be equally made up (or as equally as possible) of men and women.

For example, if 8 people, 4 males and 4 females, have the same Hourly Rate, and 2 of them are in bin 1, while 6 of them are in bin 2, I would like a 50%-50% gender percentage in each bin (1 male and 1 female in bin 1 and the rest in bin 2).

Another example, if 6 people, 4 males and 2 females, have the same Hourly Rate, and 3 of them are in bin 1, while 3 are in bin 2, I would like to have 2 males and 1 female in bin 1, and 2 males and 1 female in bin 2.

I am sending a sample dataframe, and explanations on what I have done so far:

```
data = [[1, 'M', 5.00] , [2, 'F', 5.00] , [3, 'M', 7.00] , [4, 'M', 8.00] , [5, 'M', 8.00] ,
    [6, 'F', 8.00] , [7, 'F', 8.00] , [8, 'F', 8.00] , [9, 'F', 8.00] , [10, 'M', 10.00] ,
    [11, 'M', 11.00] , [12, 'F', 12.00] , [13, 'M', 15.00] , [14, 'M', 15.00] , [15, 'M', 15.00] ,
    [16, 'F', 15.00] , [17, 'F', 15.00] , [18, 'M', 16.00] , [19, 'F', 17.00] , [20, 'F', 20.00]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Pers. Number', 'Gender', 'Hourly Rate'])
```

I rank my data, giving unique ranks to each raw (I use scipy stats for that):

```
df["Hourly Rate Rank"] = ss.rankdata(df['Hourly Rate'], method='ordinal')
```

And then I create the bins:

```
hrtotal = df['Hourly Rate'].count()

def HRQuartile(row):
    if row['Hourly Rate Rank'] <= hrtotal/4:
        val = 1
    elif row['Hourly Rate Rank'] <= (hrtotal/4)*2:
        val = 2
    elif row['Hourly Rate Rank'] <= (hrtotal/4)*3:
        val = 3
    else:
        val = 4
    return val

df['Hourly Rate Quartile'] = df.apply(HRQuartile, axis=1)
```

So up to here it works fine, I get my ranking and my equal bins.

Now, I do the following to get the problematic quartiles:

```
f = df.groupby(['Hourly Rate Quartile', 'Hourly Rate']).size().reset_index(name='Count')

ff = f[f.groupby(['Hourly Rate'])['Hourly Rate Quartile'].transform('nunique')>1]
```

And, after that I don't know how to proceed. Can anyone provide any ideas?

Also, if you have any suggestions on how to make this code more efficient, I would love to hear it.

Thank you!